# Riesz representation theorem with Stieltjes integral?

Tags: functional-analysis, riesz-representation-theorem, stieltjes-integral

I am a bit new to functional analysis and I stumbled upon this problem that confuses me.

Consider the space $X$ of bounded, non-decreasing, right-continuous functionals $F$ on $[0,1]$. Specifically, the space of cumulative distribution functions on $[0,1]$ is a subset of $X$. I have a linear functional $\varphi$ defined on $X$ through a set of properties. Intuitively (based on my knowledge of the specific function $\varphi$), it seems obvious that it should be of the form
$$ \varphi(F) = \int_0^1 G_\varphi(z) dF(z) $$
for some function $G_\varphi$. Also, it seems obvious that $G_\varphi \in X$.

Now, I am trying to prove this using the Riesz representation theorem. For this, we need an inner product on $X$. My first attempt was to define an "inner product" $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle : X \times X \to \mathbb{R}$ of the form
$$ \langle F, G \rangle = \int_0^1 G(z) dF(z)$$
If I blindly apply the Riesz representation theorem using this "inner product" and recover "Riesz representer" $G_\varphi$ using properties of $\varphi$, then I get exactly the answer I expect. The problem, however, is that $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ defined above is *not* an inner product, as it is not symmetric.

An alternative would be to move to a space $Y$ in which the derivatives of $F \in X$ live (i.e., define $\varphi$ as a function of the pdf $f \in Y$ corresponding to the original cdf $F \in X$ instead), which has the suitable inner product
$$ \langle f, g \rangle = \int_0^1 f(z) g(z) dz.$$
The problem is that the cdf $F(z)$ in my problem does not necessarily have a derivative $f
(z)$, especially at $z = 1$.

Does anyone know whether there exists a version of the Riesz representation theorem that can deal with the stieltjes integral above? Or are there other creative suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What topology are you putting on $X$? You say that $\varphi$ is a *continuous linear functional* on $X$. While the meaning of linearity can be guessed even though $X$ is only a convex cone and not a vector space, the continuity part remains a mystery.

Comment: Sorry, scrap the word "continuous" (I edited it out now). I did not put any topology on $X$.

Comment: What do you know about $\varphi$? Without any assumption, it's not guaranteed that a suitable $G_\varphi$ exists.